# Populating RecyclerView with ListArray

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am populating my recycler view with the list array. I already tried the String Array to be it is not working out for me. am i doing it all wrong or do i have to use an arrayadapter?

if i had to go array adapter how could i do it? I already have populated listview with arrayadapter but as i am in a middle of ocean i don't want to try something big. the code for my recyclerview adapter is as follow.

it doesn't show an error. but the view is populating with the last item on array.

```
public class AudioRecycleViewAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
private  List<String> values = Arrays.asList ("Al Feel","Al Humazah","Al 
Kausar","Al Maoon","Al Quresh","Dr Israr",
        "Al Kafiroon","An Nasr","Al Lahab","Al Ikhlaas","Al Falaq","An 
Naas","Iman Part 1",
        "Iman Part 2","Iman Part 3","Iman Part 4","Iman Part 5");

Context context;
InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
private int audiolayout;
public TextView txtHeader;
public TextView txtFooter;
TextView txtarabic;


public AudioRecycleViewAdapter(List<String> values, int audiolayout, Context context, InterstitialAd intAdView ) throws IOException {
    this.audiolayout = audiolayout;
    this.context = context;
    this.mInterstitialAd = intAdView;
}
public Context getContext() {
    context = this.getContext();
    return context;
}

// Provide a reference to the views for each data item
// Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
// you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public View layout;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        layout = v;
        txtHeader = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.audio_subtitle);
        txtFooter = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.audio_title);
        txtarabic = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.arabic_title);
    }
}

public void add(int position, String item) {
    values.add(position, item);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

public void remove(int position) {
    values.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public AudioRecycleViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(
            parent.getContext());

    View v =
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.audio_row_layout, parent, false);
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);

    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    int x;
    for(position =0; position < values.size(); position++)
    {
        txtHeader.setText(values.get(position));
        position++;
    }

}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return values.size();
}

}
```

Comment: Can you share your error log?

Comment: not showing error... its populating the last item on the list over every row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Use your customize ViewHolder inside `AudioRecycleViewAdapter` so change this

```
extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
```

to this

```
extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AudioRecycleViewAdapter.ViewHolder>
```

Second : you are going through all elements, just to display last value in textHeader and also use `holder.txtHeader`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.txtHeader.setText(values.get(position));

}
```

Third : Child views of item Layout view, should be inside `ViewHolder` so

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public View layout;
    public TextView txtHeader;
    public TextView txtFooter;
    public TextView txtarabic;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        layout = v;
        txtHeader = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.audio_subtitle);
        txtFooter = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.audio_title);
        txtarabic = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.arabic_title);
    }
}
```

Comment: already tried that, method doesn't override with super class erorr occurred

Comment: @ManzoorAhmad yeah, due to old method signatures so remove the old methods and let the studio override the methods with new signatures, then you will see `AudioRecycleViewAdapter.ViewHolder` as param in `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: Ok let me change that.. don't go buddy ,,,

Comment: but i want Recycler.Viewholder holde to be in param.

Comment: @ManzoorAhmad move the views inside holder , try updated answer

Answer (score 0):

As addition to Pavneet_Singh's answer, you can also add bind() method to your custom ViewHolder and bind the data related to RecyclerView item in this method. I used this approach in simple projects when things became more complicated. It should work like this:

```
//adapter's inner
class SomeClassViewHolder(val view: View) extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    //here can be view initializing, like
    txtHeader = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.audio_subtitle);

    void bind(int position){
        // all view binding logic goes here, for example:
        txtHeader.setText("someText");
    }
}

//and then in adapter
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(values.get(position));
}
```

**Edit:** with proper usage this should help you to avoid problems with finding `holder`'s bound properties, like `textView` etc. Additionally, in the future you can action holder's items listeners in the `bind()` method.